# rmANOVA or mixed models when all assumptions are violated

Tags: mixed-model, assumptions

I conducted a balanced 3x2x2 (Distance x Scale x Object) within subject design with 13 participants in my final analysis. The dependent variable is a continuous  physiological measurement with about 18k single data points per participant.

Basically, I just want to know about the main effects, interactions as well as post hoc results. I don't want to include other predictors.

The modern way approaching this kind of analysis seems to be with a mixed model using `nlme`, i.e.

```
baseline <-lme(Angle ~ 1, random = ~1|Subject/Object/Scale/Distance,
                       data = data, method = "ML")
DistanceM <- update(baseline, .~. + Distance)
ScaleM <- update(DistanceM, .~. + Scale)
ObjectM <- update(ScaleM, .~. + Object)
Distance_ScaleM <- update(ObjectM, .~. + Distance:Scale)
Distance_ObjectM <- update(Distance_ScaleM, .~. + Distance:Object)
Scale_ObjectM <- update(Distance_ObjectM, .~. + Scale:Object)
Distance_Scale_ObjectMLog <- update(Scale_ObjectM, .~. + Distance:Scale:Object)
```

**BUT:** This model basically violates all assumptions belonging to a mixed model

The old fashioned approach using `ezANOVA`, i.e. in my case:

```
rmANOVA <-ezANOVA(data = data, dv = .(Angle), wid = .(Subject),
                 within = .(Object,Scale,Distance), detailed = TRUE, type = 3)
```

violates the assumption of normal distribution and sphericity (within the distance main effect and one interaction).

In the absence of a robust alternative, what analysis would you recommend to me?

**EDIT:** I added the residuals vs. fitted values plot of the final mixed model, which I would interpret as given heteroscedasticity and non-linearity. 
[image]

Comment: The only assumption you mention is normality - but normality of what ? It is the residuals that should be normal - that's all - and even if this is violated, it it not necessarily a problem for mixed models. What other assumptions are you referring to by "all assumptions are violated" ?

Comment: Additional to the not normal residuals, the assumptions of linearity and the homogeneity of variance are not met. Or are these assumptions not necessary in my case?

Comment: linearity is by far the most important assumption.  If this is clearly violated then you should investigate why and change the model accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments so far. Wouldn´t it then be more appropriate for me to just run a rmANOVA with Greenhouse-Geisser correction of the degrees of freedom?Since Iam just not very familiar with mixed models (as you might have already guessed).

Comment: I would not recommend that. If you have reason to believe the associations are non-linear then you should attempt to model the non-linearity.